# Why do top and csysdig give different memory usage information?

Tags: performance-monitoring, memory-usage, top

I loaded a large dataset into memory in python as follows:

`data = dict(np.load(open('/path/to/data', 'rb')))`

`free` and `top` (and also `htop`) both show that a lot of memory is in use:

`$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            62G         42G        354M         41M         20G         20G
Swap:           63G        447M         63G`

`$ top
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
 6830 gmr       20   0 42.265g 0.041t   7296 S   0.0 66.1  34:52.22 ipython`

But `csysdig` shows much less memory usage:

`$ sudo csysdig
   PID     CPU USER          TH     VIRT      RES    FILE     NET Command
  6830    0.00 gmr           13       2G       2G       0    0.00 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/ipython`

What is the reason for this discrepancy?

Comment: Are you doing anything unusual that you didn't mention, such as using virtualization of some kind?

Comment: Nope, running Ubuntu 16.04 on bare metal.

Comment: I wonder if it's a bug/limitation in sysdig that causes it to mishandle amounts over 2GB.